# R flextable caption not adhering to word style

Tags: r, flextable, officer

I'm using `officer` and `flextable` to create captioned tables in a report exported to word. I've been setting "Table Caption" as the word style, and indeed the exported word doc has the caption identified as the style "Table Caption". However, the title section of the caption does not follow the set word style. The "Table #:" part does, but the caption words do not. The caption words show up as Arial. If I change the flextable font via `set_flextable_options`, the caption words will be in that font.

The same result occurs regardless of how the caption is set, i.e. via `tab.cap` and `tab.cap.style` or via `set_caption`. I made a new word style in case something was weird with the default "Table Caption" and used that in `tab.cap.style` and the same thing happens. It shows as set to that style but doesn't follow the font properties of the style. The "Table #:" part comes out as expected.

Example:

````
---
title: "flextable caption example"
output:
   officedown::rdocx_document:
    reference_docx: ref.docx
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(officedown)
library(officer)
library(flextable)

knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  echo = FALSE,
  tab.cap.style = "Table Caption",
  tab.cap.pre = "Table",
  tab.cap.sep = ":")
```

```{r echo=FALSE, tab.cap="airquality dataset", tab.id="tab1"}
ft <- qflextable(head(airquality))
ft
```
````

The image is with "airquality dataset" selected. Expected output would be for the entire caption to be in the same style as "Table 1:" is.

[image]

My search hasn't come across any instance of this issue, and from following the online user guides I believe I am doing it correctly. In fact, running sample code from online does the exact same thing.

If I'm missing something, please let me know. Or if there's another way to set the caption font properties other than identifying a word style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having this same issue, but it resolved when I reinstalled the flextable package on 11/18/2022. Now, both the figure and table captions in the knitted Word doc appear correctly bolded. (The reinstall also fixed a problem I was having with tables breaking across pages correctly.) Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it actually solved the issue for me. I upgraded from `flextable 0.6.6` to `flextable 0.9.2` to be a bit more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You should move to `bookdown::word_document2:`, instead of `officedown::rdocx_document:` . Simply add the following lines to your YAML =>

```
knit: "bookdown::render_book"
output: 
  bookdown::word_document2:
    reference_docx: "path/to_the/REFERENCE_DOCX.docx"
```

With `bookdown::word_document2`, **it should works correctly**, no matter if you:

A) use a global parameter for the chunks ( `knitr::opts_chunk$set(tab.cap.style = "Table Caption")` )

B) add `tab.cap.style = "Table Caption"` in a single code chunk parameters ( `{r echo=FALSE, tab.cap="airquality dataset", tab.cap.style = "Table Caption", tab.id="tab1"}` )

C) or use the following code inside the chunk:

```
ft <- qflextable(head(airquality))

ft <- set_caption(ft, "airquality dataset",     
    style = "Table Caption", 
    autonum = run_autonum(seq_id = "tab", bkm = "tab1")) 
ft
```

Comment: All my packages are up to date. I don't have the `qflextable` in my personal code, I was just mirroring the documentation online. I either use `flextable` or `as_flex_table` from the `gtsummary` package and it does the same with both. And I mentioned it but didn't add the full code in the original post but the `set_caption` method does the exact same thing. I just checked the single code chunk option as well, no change. The whole thing is just very odd.

Comment: Wow, I see the problem. I've edited my answer :)

Comment: Still does the same thing. I mean I can go through and just reapply the style so it's ultimately a solvable problem. It is just so so odd and I don't like not understanding why it's not working lol